# Trigger insert/update how to test if something was inserted and update x

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm very new to triggers (never had to use them before this past month).

How can I test if a row is inserted in one table with a unique identifier and update another table?

For instance:

```
1   table 1
2   id 1  name max  last: headroom
3   id 2  name john last: sewer<-- newly inserted
4    
5   updated table 2
6   id 1 address: hhhhhhh   initials: m.h.
7   id 2 address: gggggggg  initials: <--update this
```

This is how I do updates:

```
01  CREATE TRIGGER Alabama_ID_UPDATE_USERRWAY ON USERRWAY
02  FOR  UPDATE
03  AS
04  BEGIN
05      SET NOCOUNT ON
06      IF (UPDATE(ST_LOCL_ID))
07      BEGIN
08          DECLARE @BRKEY VARCHAR(15)             
09          SET @BRKEY = (SELECT BRKEY FROM inserted) 
10          DECLARE @ALABAMA_ID VARCHAR(20)
11          SET @ALABAMA_ID = (SELECT ALABAMA_ID FROM USERBRDG WHERE USERBRDG.BRKEY = @BRKEY)  
12                        
13          BEGIN
14              DECLARE @ST_LOCL_ID VARCHAR(4)    
15              SET @ST_LOCL_ID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(USERRWAY.ST_LOCL_ID,1,4)FROM USERRWAY WHERE USERRWAY.BRKEY = @BRKEY AND ON_UNDER = '1')
16          END
17          BEGIN
18              IF(@ALABAMA_ID IS NOT NULL)
19              BEGIN
20                  SET @ALABAMA_ID = STUFF(@ALABAMA_ID, 15, 4, @ST_LOCL_ID)
21                  UPDATE USERBRDG SET USERBRDG.ALABAMA_ID = @ALABAMA_ID WHERE USERBRDG.BRKEY =  @BRKEY
22              END 
23              ELSE
24              BEGIN
25                  SET @ALABAMA_ID = ('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
26                  SET @ALABAMA_ID = STUFF(@ALABAMA_ID, 15, 4, @ST_LOCL_ID)
27                  UPDATE USERBRDG SET USERBRDG.ALABAMA_ID = @ALABAMA_ID WHERE USERBRDG.BRKEY =  @BRKEY
28              END 
29          END
30      END
31  END
32  GO
```

An example of what I want to do is:

If someone inserts a row into a structure unit I need to update:

```
UPDATE USERBRDG 
SET USERBRDG.ALABAMA_ID = @ALABAMA_ID 
WHERE USERBRDG.BRKEY = @BRKEY
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken. Triggers run once per *statement* and `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Which means `SET @BRKEY = (SELECT BRKEY FROM inserted)` is going to get *one* value and ignore the others (or be `NULL` if there were 0 rows)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the above trigger works exactly how we need it to work.  I would like to know how to write one that will work after a row is inserted into one table but i need to update another table

Comment: No, the trigger *appears* to work, but you'll find problems as soon as someone writes an `UPDATE` that affects more than one row.